# Ning's AsyncHttpClient don't use proxy when requesting HTTPS page

Tags: java, proxy, asynchttpclient

I'm using [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) (1.9.x version) to make requests via proxy:

```
  private AsyncHttpClientConfig cfg = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder( ).
                setConnectTimeout( 20000 ).
                setRequestTimeout( 20000 ).
                setWebSocketTimeout(20000).
                setMaxRequestRetry(3).
                setReadTimeout( 20000 ).
                setAcceptAnyCertificate( true ).
                build( )

   private AsyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient( cfg )


  client.prepareGet( url ).
                 setProxyServer( new ProxyServer( ProxyServer.Protocol.HTTP, "myproxyurl", 2222, "principal", "password" ) ).
                 execute( ).
                 get()
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to request HTTP*S* page, then proxy server isn't used. But when I'm requesting HTTP URL it works fine and uses proxy server I defined.

Comment: Are you sure about the constructor `new ProxyServer( ProxyServer.Protocol.HTTP, "myproxyurl", 2222, "principal", "password" )` ? It doesn't match the class here [link](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/client/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/proxy/ProxyServer.java). ProxyServer.Protocol doesn't exists.

Comment: @Giovanni sorry, I'm using stable version branch (1.9.x). This is the link to `ProxyServer` class - https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/1.9.x/src/main/java/com/ning/http/client/ProxyServer.java

Comment: So maybe you should pass ProxyServer.Protocol.HTTPS instead of HTTP when you need to make a HTTPS request

Comment: @Giovanni it didn't help

Answer (score 2):

AHC 1 ProxyServer API is broken (it's fixed in upcoming AHC 2).
With AHC 1, you have to pass `ProxyServer.Protocol.HTTPS` when dealing with https.